# ¿Cómo dividir un archivo de audio (.mp3 o .wav) en partes de 10 segundos para enviar sus partes a una función?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

Estaba teniendo problemas a la hora de fragmente un audio (.mp3 o .wav) en partes si este superase los 10 segundos de largo. He conseguido establecer la condición pero no hallo modo de poder realizar la separación.

```py
import librosa

x = 10 #parametro de tiempo (en segundos) para dividir archivo de audio (.mp3 o .wav)

def processing_audio(audio_chunk):
    return text

input_audio_file = "CLASE 9 HOMBRE MAQUINA.mp3" #duracion 14:18 minutos
speech, rate = librosa.load(input_audio_file, sr=16000) #cargado en frecuencia de 16 kHz

len_data = len(speech)  # holds length of the numpy array
duration_in_seconds = int( len_data / rate ) # returns duration in seconds but in floats
print(duration_in_seconds)

if(duration_in_seconds >= x): 
    print("debe crear los archivos separados cada uno menor a 10 segundos")

    #AQUI EL PROBLEMA

    for audio_chunk in audio_chunks:
        print(repr(processing_audio(audio_chunk))
else:
    print("no es necesario separar")
    print(repr(processing_audio(speech))
```

Comment: no conozco la librería que usas por lo que no sé si podrás usar slicing. Conozco la librería `pydub` la cual si te permite usar slicing, así todo se reduce a hacer `audio[inicio: fin]`

Comment: la librería que menciona @Christian debería servir para lo que necesitas

Comment: No es necesario utilizar la libreria librosa, yo la use porque la habia usado antes y la creí conveniente pero puede hacerse por medio de otra o combinando varias. He intentado con pydub pero he tenido algunas dificultades con ella, a que te refieres con lo del slicing?

Comment: @Christian Estaba probando, es posible aplicar ese slicing sobre lo almacenado en la variable `speech` ? algo que se me ocurrió para obtener el numero de particiones es hacer `duration_in_seconds/x` , y si tiene decimal redondear siempre para el siguiente entero, aun asi no logro plantear ese slicing que probablemente deba estar dentro de un bucle `for` para que se haga tantas veces como divisiones, y en alguna carpeta haría almacenando las partes

Comment: Te valdría si hago una respuesta mostrando como sería con la librería `pydub`?

Comment: @Christian Si no hay problema con que librería sea, me ayudarías un montón la verdad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la librería `pydub` tu problema se vuelve más fácil de resolver, pues esta librería nos permite usar *slicing* para obtener pedazos de un audio. El slicing es usar la notación de corchetes en un objeto para poder extraer parte de su contenido, su sintaxis sería esto:

```py
# object[inicio: fin: paso]
print("cadena de texto"[0: 3]) 
# por defecto el inicio es 0, el fin es la longitud del iterable y el paso 1
```

Para poder usar la librería `pydub` debes tener instalado `ffmpeg` e instalar `pydub` con `pip`, luego de todo esto ya podemos empezar.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
import math

seg = 10

input_audio_file = "CLASE 9 HOMBRE MAQUINA.mp3" 
speech = AudioSegment.from_mp3(input_audio_file)

batch_size = seg * 1000
duracion = speech.duration_seconds
batches = math.ceil(duracion / seg)

inicio = 0
for i in range(batches):
    pedazo = speech[inicio: inicio + batch_size]
    pedazo.export(f'pedazo_{i}.mp3', format='mp3') #guardamos el audio de 10s
    inicio+= batch_size
```

Con ese código ya tendríamos todo. Dentro del ciclo for utilizamos el slicing para obtenet cada fragmento del audio riginal, esto gracias a la variable `inicio` que nos dice desde donde comenzar y siempre lo tomaremos hasta `inicio + batch_size` lo que indica que tomaremos desde donde nos hayamos quedado hasta 10 segundos más y así hasta el final. Si tienes alguna duda déjala en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Muchicimas gracias, tan solo cambie la variable `audio` por `speech`, y funciono perfecto!

Comment: Ay, me había olvidado cambiarlo  lo puse diferente en el codigo que estaba haciendo.